# Unit tests with an unmanaged external read-only database

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm working on a project which involves a huge external dataset (~490Gb) loaded in an external database (MS SQL through django-pyodbc-azure). I've generated the Django models marked `managed=False` in their meta. In my application this works fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to run my unit tests. I can think of two approaches: mocking the data in a test database, and giving the unit tests (and CI) read-only access to the production dataset. Both options are acceptable, but I can't figure out either of them:

**Option 1: Mocked data**
Because my models are marked `managed=False`, there are no migrations, and as a result, the test runner fails to create the database.

**Option 2: Live data** 
`django-pyodbc-azure` will attempt to create a test database, which fails because it has a read-only connection. Also I suspect that even if it were allowed to do so, the resulting database would be missing the required tables.

**Q** How can I run my unittests? Installing additional packages, or reconfiguring the database is acceptable. My setup uses django 1.9 with postgresql for the main DB.

Answer (score 2):

After a day of staring at my screen, I found a solution:

I removed the `managed=True` from the models, and generated migrations. To prevent actual migrations against the production database, I used my database router to prevent the migrations. (return False in `allow_migrate` when for the appropriate app and database).

In my settings I detect whether unittests are being run, and then just don't define the database router or the external database. With the migrations present, the unit tests.

Comment: I posted a response to your answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350023/estimating-total-events-from-buckets-hit  can you clarify?